# Return input information in android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, computer-science

I am new to android studio and I am trying to play with simple program that takes an input from the user such as name, certification number, and role and display the user input as an output. I am using a separate java file that I have created that has all of the methods to access. Because I am new to android studio I am unsure of the syntax on how to achieve this. Could you please provide the correct way of writing the syntax so that I get the desired output?

I will be providing the xml.file, the java file associated with the .xml file and the second java file which has the class and methods to pull from. DivingDuddy.java is dependent on Divepartner.java. I added Divepartner to the android library. See code below and thank you again.

The .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DivingBuddy">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dive_buddypage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Welcome to the Dive Buddy section!"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.051" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/divebuddyname_input"
        android:layout_width="249dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_custom"
        android:hint="Enter Name:"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.098"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.241" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/certNumber_input"
        android:layout_width="249dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_custom"
        android:hint="Enter certNumber of partner:"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.098"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.347" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/role_input"
        android:layout_width="249dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_custom"
        android:hint="Enter role of partner:"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.098"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.451" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_custom"
        android:hint="Dive Section Output:"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.649" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/complete_DiveBuddySection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Complete"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.806" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back_to_otherDetails3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.901" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Java file associated with the .xml file is called DivingBuddy.java.

```
public class DivingBuddy extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name, certNum, role, output;
    Button back;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diving_buddy);

        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.divebuddyname_input);
        certNum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.certNumber_input);
        role = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.role_input);
        output = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.output);

        findViewById(R.id.complete_DiveBuddySection).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                DivePartner divePartner = new DivePartner(" "," "," ");
                String inputName = name.getText().toString();
                String inputCertNumber = certNum.getText().toString();
                String inputRole = role.getText().toString();
                String dive_buddy_info = output.getText().toString();

                if(inputName.isEmpty() || inputCertNumber.isEmpty() || inputRole.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(DivingBuddy.this,"Please Enter the Name, CertNumber and role of the dive partner", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{

                    inputName = divePartner.getName();
                    inputCertNumber = divePartner.getCertNum();
                    inputRole = divePartner.getRole();
                    dive_buddy_info = divePartner.toString();

                    System.out.println(inputName);
                    System.out.println(inputCertNumber);
                    System.out.println(inputRole);
                    System.out.println(dive_buddy_info);
                }
            }
        });

        back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back_to_otherDetails3);

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),OtherDivingDetails.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The third Java file is called DivePartner.java which is used to call methods or functions from.

```
package com.example.divepartner;

public class DivePartner {
    private String name;
    private String certNum;
    private String role;

    public DivePartner(String name, String number, String role){
        setName(name);
        setCertNum(number);
        setRole(role);
    }

    public String getName() {
        String temp = name;
        return temp;
    }

    private void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCertNum() {
        String temp = certNum;
        return temp;
    }

    private void setCertNum(String certNum) {
        this.certNum = certNum;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        String temp = role;
        return temp;
    }

    private void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + getName() + ", CertNum: " + getCertNum() + ", Role: " + getRole();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a plenty of tutorials online. Please complete the basics before jumping to  android development.

Answer (score 0):

```java
DivePartner divePartner = new DivePartner(" "," "," ");
// ....
// ....
// ....
inputName = divePartner.getName();
inputCertNumber = divePartner.getCertNum();
inputRole = divePartner.getRole();
dive_buddy_info = divePartner.toString();
```

The `DivePartner` object is empty. So, when you call the `get()` methods on it, it will return a `null` or `empty` value. So, use `set()` instead of `get()`.

```java
DivePartner divePartner = new DivePartner(" "," "," ");
// ....
// ....
// ....
divePartner.setName(inputName);
divePartner.setCertNum(inputCertNumber);
divePartner.getRole(inputRole);

dive_buddy_info = divePartner.toString();
```

Now instead of `System.out.println()`, use `Log.d()` method to log in AndroidStudio Console.

**I highly recommend you to complete a basic Java course before starting Android Development**

Comment: thank you for your help. I really appreciate you taking the time to give me some guidance. I am in the middle of taking a Java course now as a refresher. But, I like to come here to learn from you fine people. If that is okay of course.

Comment: setName is private. I can not access it unless it is public and I do not want to make it public. I was able to get the desired input/output when I was calling the java file from a regular java file and not an android studio java file and it worked. So, I am not sure why I can not do the same thing since this is based off of java. This is why I needed a little help with the syntax guidance. But, I am sure you know what you are talking about, so I will continue to do what you suggested.